# Draw line graph with dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark-sql

How can I use `matplotlib` to draw multiple line(based on different app) graph (hour on x bar, counts on y bar) with the results of `sparksql`?

Should I convert it to pandas dataframe first?

The results are:

```
+---+------+---------------+
| hr|counts|            app|
+---+------+---------------+
| 00|  1770|   "BitTorrent"|
| 01|  2744|   "BitTorrent"|
| 02|  2998|   "BitTorrent"|
| 03| 13717|   "BitTorrent"|
| 04|   417|   "BitTorrent"|
| 10|  3497|   "BitTorrent"|
| 11|  9037|   "BitTorrent"|
| 00|    14|          "DNS"|
| 01|    19|          "DNS"|
| 02|    49|          "DNS"|
| 03|    54|          "DNS"|
| 10|    19|          "DNS"|
| 11|    17|          "DNS"|
| 00|   954| "HTTP.BROWSER"|
| 01|  1707| "HTTP.BROWSER"|
| 02|    15| "HTTP.BROWSER"|
+---+------+---------------+
```

And other question is can I fill the other hour not shown in the results with different app?

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you've tried and people can give you specific feedback on it rather than guessing.

Comment: Start with the code from an [example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html) and try to make it work with your code. If you get stuck post what you've done and we'll go from there